# Website Navigation Structure: Should I restructure a submenu that is not using a <li>?

Tags: wordpress, menu, navigation, search-engine

I recently started working on an (existing) WordPress site navigation menu, and noticed that the person who built it did not use the normal structure for the submenu (a list with list items). They were trying to create a megamenu but weren't sure how, so they created a paragraph with links inside of a section and injected it into the submenu. My question is, are search engines going to have trouble reading this code/determining the menu structure? Should I restructure it as a regular submenu with an unordered list and list items? Are there any other reasons I should restructure these submenus or should I heave them as-is?

The submenus are currently structured like this (in addition to the section structure that might be bogging down the code):

```
<p>
  <a href="https://link here">Link 1</a>
  <br>
  <a href="https://link here">Link 2</a>
  <br>
  <a href="https://link here">Link 3</a>
</p>
```

And I'm wondering if I should rebuild it like this:

```
<ul>
   <li>
      <a href="https://link here">Link 1</a>
   <li>
      <a href="https://link here">Link 2</a>
  <li>
      <a href="https://link here">Link 3</a>
</ul>
```

Comment: Search engines will have no trouble finding links within the first example. The bigger question, is all of if wrapped in a `nav` tag? That's more for semantics - but will help accessibility tools know that they are in a menu.